# How to add value to specific form's input through jQuery

Tags: jquery

Given this HTML:

```
<form id="formx">
  <input type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#formx>input").attr('value') = "my text";
})
```

Why isn't it working? [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/ubZbZ/) a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
$("#formx>input").attr('value', 'my text');
```

or this

```
$("#formx>input").val('my text');
```

You can't assign a value to the output of a function.

Answer (score 1):

give your input an ID and access it using that. Or use:

```
$("#formx input").val("my text");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a value using .attr() incorrectly. Should be like:

```
$(function() {
  $("#formx>input").attr('value',"my text");
})​
```